# Can't build solution due to TypeScript errors, but noEmitOnError is false

Tags: c#, typescript, visual-studio-2015, tsconfig

I'm working on a ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 web application with React and TypeScript in Visual Studio 2015 with ReSharper 2016.2. I'm using a `tsconfig.json` that looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": false,
    "removeComments": false,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react"

  },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "wwwroot",
        "typings/index.d.ts",
        "typings/index",
        "jspm_packages"
    ],
    "compileOnSave": true
}
```

As you can see, `noEmitOnError` is false. However, after installing Update 3, Visual Studio no longer lets me build the solution if there are any typing errors. Every TS error is reported twice in the error list:

[image]

And the first error, without the error code, stops the solution from building.

I've tried:

1. Reinstalling/Uninstalling TypeScript tools for VS (doesn't change anything)
2. Recreating the `tsconfig.json` file.
3. Switching to the mode without `tsconfig.json` and making sure emit on error is enabled.
4. Disabling/enabling ReSharper
5. Uninstalling various other extensions
6. Creating a new project and solution. The error occurs in all projects.

The only solution I've found to the issue is removing the following line from the `.csproj` file:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets')" />
```

After I do this, the TypeScript tooling still works fine (there are a few minor issues) and the error that begins with `Build:` disappears.

The problem is that after some operations on `.ts` files Visual Studio raises the following helpful message:

[image]

And helpfully adds that line to the `.csproj` file again. At first everything is okay, but the `Build:` error comes back after I restart Visual Studio.

#### Edit: Better Workaround

Okay, a better workaround is to replace the bad line with the following:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" Condition="False And Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets')" />
```

This 'tricks' VS into believing that the line already exists so it won't add it again. However, there are still issues, such as errors only appearing if you open the file containing the error, rather than on build.

Comment: Do you mean that it works well before you install the update 3?

Comment: @JackZhai Yes, it worked perfectly. It reported errors on build but still built the project.